# Passing Session in Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, azure, servicestack

I have writing unit tests for my services.I have used Azure Active Directory for Authentication. Now while passing the sessions using `MockHttpRequest` i am getting exception as `Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.AuthUserSession' to type 'AadAuthSession'.`Here is my code in Testbase class.

```
  IAuthSession session = new AadAuthSession();
        session.UserName = "Author";
        appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => session,
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new AadAuthProvider(appHost.AppSettings),
            }
   ));
```

Am i missing something ..How to cast it correctly ?

```
public TestBase()
    {
        appHost = new TestAppHost().Init();
        appHost.TestMode = true;
        appHost.AppSettings = new AppSettings();
        appHost.Container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider));
        appHost.Container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        IAuthSession session = new AadAuthSession();
        appHost.Container.Register<IAuthSession>(c => session);
        session.UserName = "Author";
        appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => session,
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new AadAuthProvider(appHost.AppSettings),
            }
        ));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the Session using an IOC if you set your AppHost to `TestMode` with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { TestMode = true });
```

Which will let you register a Session that gets returned when a Session is requested, i.e:

```
IAuthSession session = new AadAuthSession();
container.Register<IAuthSession>(c => session);
```

Another way to mock the session is to register it in `IRequest.Items`, e.g:

```
req.Items[SessionFeature.RequestItemsSessionKey] = session;
```

Comment: I am using the first option of mocking of session into IOC and set the TestMode = true , still getting the same error ..Is there any kind of type cast missing or required ..I have updated my code..Please have a look at the post..

Comment: @Lara are you using the latest v4.0.50 version of ServiceStack? if so what's the StackTrace? MockHttpRequest may require you to inherit from AuthUserSession instead.

Comment: I have added the required code for `MockHttpRequest()` please have a look at my updated post and let me know what needs to be added ...

Comment: @Lara you didn't bother to answer any of my questions??

Comment: @Lara please don't paste code or dump outputs in comments, please update your question with the **full StackTrace**. Also add the version of ServiceStack you're using - please do this for all future questions. But I expect like the exception says you need to inherit from `AuthUserSession`.